# Kommunicate chat widget becomes transparent with custom settings

Tags: javascript, html, dialogflow-es, chatbot, kommunicate

I have integrated [Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io) service into [my website](https://zoneofcode.com) and added a `Dialogflow` chatbot into it.

I have added the `kommunicate` widget successfuly and it worked well with the configurations as shown below:

```
var kommunicateSettings = {
    "appId":"APP-ID",
    "conversationTitle":"SAMPLE",
};
```

But when I add the following settings, the widget asks to enter the name and email and when I submit it, the widget disappears with a transparent box with a shadow:

```
var kommunicateSettings = {
    "appId":"APP-ID",
    "conversationTitle":"SAMPLE",
    "askUserDetails":['name', 'email'],
    "emojilibrary":true,
    "locShare":true
};
```

It does not show the chat widget now, what to do?

Comment: For what it is worth I just tried it on your site and it was empty for a moment but then it loaded in pretty quickly. Mayne the chat widget is slow to load or there is some other error on the page?

Comment: @lemieuxster But for me it is not so! It doesn't load even after 10 minutes.

Comment: Are there any errors in the development console? What browser are you using? I used Chrome. Are you using anything like an Ad Blocker that might cause it to not load?

Comment: I am using Kali Linux so I have Firefox. There are no errors in the console but only warnings that are caused by Google Analytics used in the site.

Comment: I just tried in the latest Firefox (on Mac) and it also worked there. Have you looked at the network tab? Maybe something is being blocked by a firewall or proxy? Also, there might be a difference between if you are loading it from localhost or something.

Comment: I have network access, not from localhost.

Comment: Please do not add "please help" pleading messages into your questions. It can have [a counterproductive effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was related to `askUserDetails` parameter. When `askUserDetails` parameter was passed, it was loading some firefox incompatible CSS which was causing this behavior.
Now, this issue is fixed and not reproducible in the latest version of Kommuncate chat SDK.

PS: I work for [Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io/)